# Azure AppFabric Service Bus Echo sample not working

Tags: azure, appfabric

I'm trying to run the Echo sample between two machines on my local network. The sample uses the netTcpRelayBinding and it works fine if I run both the service and the client on the same machine.
When I first compiled the services and put it on my other machine, a Windows 2003 Server with no dev tools installed. It wouldn't run because it didn't know what netTcpRelayBinding was in the app.config. So I moved the config to code only and the service started. I confirmed this with the Service Bus Explorer.
I then tried to connect with my dev machine (through VS2010) but it won't work. I have tried to change stuff both on the service and the client, trying all the combination of settings I can think of, but nothing. 
I mostly get one of two errors on the client:

"ContractDescription 'IEchoContract' has zero operations; a contract must have at least one operation."

or

"there was no endpoint listening that could accept the message".

This is the server code, my change is between the custom comments.

```
// create the service URI based on the service namespace
        Uri address = ServiceBusEnvironment.CreateServiceUri("sb", serviceNamespace, "EchoService");

        // create the credentials object for the endpoint
        TransportClientEndpointBehavior sharedSecretServiceBusCredential = new TransportClientEndpointBehavior();
        sharedSecretServiceBusCredential.CredentialType = TransportClientCredentialType.SharedSecret;
        sharedSecretServiceBusCredential.Credentials.SharedSecret.IssuerName = issuerName;
        sharedSecretServiceBusCredential.Credentials.SharedSecret.IssuerSecret = issuerSecret;

        // create the service host reading the configuration
        ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(EchoService), address);

        // custom
        host.AddServiceEndpoint(
                    typeof(IEchoContract),
                    new NetTcpRelayBinding(),
                    "EchoService" );
        // custom end

        // create the ServiceRegistrySettings behavior for the endpoint
        IEndpointBehavior serviceRegistrySettings = new ServiceRegistrySettings(DiscoveryType.Public);

        // add the Service Bus credentials to all endpoints specified in configuration
        foreach (ServiceEndpoint endpoint in host.Description.Endpoints)
        {
            endpoint.Behaviors.Add(serviceRegistrySettings);
            endpoint.Behaviors.Add(sharedSecretServiceBusCredential);
        }

        // open the service
        host.Open();
```

This is the client code, my current change is between the custom comments:

```
// create the service URI based on the service namespace
        Uri serviceUri = ServiceBusEnvironment.CreateServiceUri("sb", serviceNamespace, "EchoService");

        // create the credentials object for the endpoint
        TransportClientEndpointBehavior sharedSecretServiceBusCredential = new TransportClientEndpointBehavior();
        sharedSecretServiceBusCredential.CredentialType = TransportClientCredentialType.SharedSecret;
        sharedSecretServiceBusCredential.Credentials.SharedSecret.IssuerName = issuerName;
        sharedSecretServiceBusCredential.Credentials.SharedSecret.IssuerSecret = issuerSecret;

        // create the channel factory loading the configuration
        //ChannelFactory<IEchoChannel> channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<IEchoChannel>("RelayEndpoint", new EndpointAddress(serviceUri));

        // custom
        ServiceEndpoint endpoint = new ServiceEndpoint(new ContractDescription("IEchoContract", "Microsoft.ServiceBus.Samples"), new NetTcpRelayBinding(EndToEndSecurityMode.Transport, RelayClientAuthenticationType.None), new EndpointAddress(serviceUri));
        ChannelFactory<IEchoChannel> channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<IEchoChannel>(endpoint);
        // custom end


        // apply the Service Bus credentials
        channelFactory.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(sharedSecretServiceBusCredential);

        // create and open the client channel
        IEchoChannel channel = channelFactory.CreateChannel();
        channel.Open();
```

My app.config files are cleared of the settings. I haven't touched any other files.

Answer (score 1):

It's because the namespace of the labs is different from the "old" appfabric. I dont know how to get it working right now. Just pretty much "Microsoft" again...

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue and when I debugged it I found that the issuerKey coming from the config is "yourkey". These values are stored in the Azure project itself, ServiceConfiguration.cscfg file. You need to place some real values there and it should be OK.

Answer (score 0):

I meet same issue then, I figue out, this example need your own service bus.
So create a service bus in your portal, then copy the issuer key's value to issure secret.